# How to make HTML select tag work with Remix Form?

Tags: remix.run

I've been exploring Remix and quite like how the Form export from Remix works. However, i can't seem to make select work with Form. Using ref to submit form does the job but reloads the page which is something I don't want. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to submit a Remix Form is by using a submit button. I assume in this case you don't want a submit button but rather submit on select?

Make sure that you are using the actual Remix Form component. The HTML form element will always trigger a full page reload.

```js
import { Form } from 'remix';
```

If your error persists, then I assume that your ref triggers the default behavior of the `form` HTML element and that's why submitting the form triggers a full page reload. To programmatically submit a Remix form, you can use the `useFetcher` hook. You can find the `useFetcher` documentation [here](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#usefetcher).

Your code will looking something like this:

```js
function Component() {
    const fetcher = useFetcher();

    const handleSelect = (selectedValue) => {
        // programmatically submit a useFetcher form in Remix
        fetcher.submit({ selected: selectedValue }, { method: "post", action: "/");
    };

    return (
        <Select onSelect={handleSelect} />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Remix team have added a new hook (**useSubmit**) to handle imperative form submissions like in my case.

Read More: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-submit